# How to count the number of repetitions that while does?

Tags: objective-c, loops, count, while-loop, numbers

I am doing a year of college and am having MUCH difficulty at a specific point ....

I need to make a code that reads the population of the U.S. and Brazil, knowing that the population of the U.S. is higher than in Brazil.

The issue is I need to count the number of the while loop, after all if 1 means 1 more year if it is 2 years older is 2 and so on. the code is here and is objective-c...

```
int pAmericana, pBrasileira, ano;


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{


@autoreleasepool {

    NSLog(@"What year is it?");
    scanf("%i", &Ano);
    NSLog(@"which the American people?");
    scanf("%i", &pAmericana);
    NSLog(@"which the Brazilian people?");
    scanf("%i", &pBrasileira);

    while (pAmericana >= pBrasileira) {

        pAmericana=(pAmericana*0.2)+pAmericana;
        pBrasileira=(pBrasileira*0.4)+pBrasileira;

    }
     //FAILURE TO KNOW HOW TO COUNT HOW OFTEN HAPPENS THE LOOP .....
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a counter inside the loop:

```
int i = 0;
while (pAmericana >= pBrasileira) {

    pAmericana=(pAmericana*0.2)+pAmericana;
    pBrasileira=(pBrasileira*0.4)+pBrasileira;
    i++;
}

NSLog(@"Loop count %i", i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a count variable to the `while` loop works. But you can also use a `for` loop:

```
int i = 0;
for (; pAmericana >= pBrasileira; i++) {
    pAmericana=(pAmericana*0.2)+pAmericana;
    pBrasileira=(pBrasileira*0.4)+pBrasileira;
}

NSLog(@"Loop executed %d times", i);
```

You must declare the variable before the `for` loop so its value is available after the loop.

Note - you can change the calculations to:

```
int i = 0;
for (; pAmericana >= pBrasileira; i++) {
    pAmericana *= 1.2;
    pBrasileira *= 1.4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`int i = 0` before the while, `i++;` in the while loop, `NSLog(@"Loops: %d", i);` after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an integer variable outside the `while` loop then increment it within the loop, like this:

```
int i = 0; // Initialise the counter

while (pAmericana >= pBrasileira) {
  ...
  i++; // Increment the counter
}
```